# Karate contract testing, please advise with an example to start

Tags: karate

Recently I started microservices development and am trying to explore contract testing using Karate framework.
I have good knowledge in Karate API automation however when it comes to contract testing, I could not gather much documentation online or good starting point. Had seen test double and consumer provider example from Github.
Please advise any example or sample code I can follow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Had seen test double and consumer provider example from Github.

In my opinion, that is more than sufficient. Just to make sure you have the right link, because this example is simplified so that you can just run it as a stand-alone Maven project - here it is: https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/master/examples/consumer-driven-contracts

If you have a specific question, please ask a new question.